# Python Regex Matching

Tags: python, regex, string, if-statement, match

I am inputting a text file (Line)(all strings). I am trying to make card_type to be true so it can enter the if statement, however, it never enters the IF statement. The output that comes out from the print line is:

```
imm48-1gb-sfp/imm48-1gb-sfp
imm-2pac-fp3/imm-2pac-fp3
imm5-10gb-xfp/imm5-10gb-xfp
sfm4-12/sfm4-12
```

This is the code:

```
    print str(card_type)            
    if card_type == re.match(r'(.*)/(.*)',line):
       card_type = card_type.group(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) will return a [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) if there's a match or `None` if there wasn't. Following code will capture the part before `/` character:

```
import re

line = 'imm48-1gb-sfp/imm48-1gb-sfp'
match = re.match(r'(.*?)/', line)
if match:
    card_type = match.group(1)
    print card_type
```

Comment: True, I've change the example to use non-greedy pattern `.*?` which will work in case input has multiple `/` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Card_type is a string. re.match() returns a Boolean (true or false, wether the regex matches the string or not).

Since they are different types, they cannot be equal and the if condition will not be fulfilled.

Comment: According to Python documentation [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) will return a [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)